# Как использовать telegram api на php?

Tags: php, telegram

Как использовать приложение в телеграмме? Не могу понять почему всюду примеры использования telegram api для бота, а как использовать обычное api telegram? я хочу получить статус пользователя по номеру телефона https://core.telegram.org/constructor/auth.checkedPhone , как мне использовать этот метод не могу понять

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, самым простым способом использовать core API телеграма будет написание обёртки для [telegram-cli](https://valtman.name/telegram-cli). К сожалению, код этой программы открыт не полностью, но тем не менее, этот клиент умеет общаться с другими процессами на JSON по каналам или сокетам. Этот режим включается ключом `--json`.

**telegram-cli** читает со стандартного потока ввода объекты-команды и отправляет на стандартный поток вывода объекты-результаты и объекты-обновления. Также он может выполнять команды, читая их из сокета (нужно указать флаг `-P`, подробнее в справке). Помимо этого на stdout и stderr он печатает и диагностические сообщения (их стоит отфильтровывать).

Каждый объект в таком CLI протоколе имеет поле `ID`, задающее тип. Все типы перечислены в TL-схеме. Также одной из особенностью **telegram-cli** является то, что все прочие поля имеют на конце нижнее подчёркивание. То есть если в схеме параметр указан как `phone_registered`, то ему соответствует поле `phone_registered_` в JSON объекте.

Подробнее смотрите пример по приведённой ссылке на домашней странице клиента или вот мой на JavaScript.

```js
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var readline = require('readline');

// задержка между перезапусками клиента, в случае сбоя
const RESTARTING_DELAY = 1000;

// список запрещённых слов, для примера
const obsceneLexicon = RegExp(...);

// основной объект для процесса telegram-cli
var tg;

function launchTelegram() {
  tg = spawn('./telegram-cli', ['--json', '-DCR'],
             { stdio: ['ipc', 'pipe', process.stderr] });
  readline.createInterface({ input: tg.stdout }).on('line', function(data) {
    try {
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.name == 'SyntaxError') {
        // клиент иногда отправлет не только json, обычный текст обрабатывать не
        // надо, просто выведем для удобной дальнейшей отладки
        console.log(data.toString());
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
    if (obj) {
      processUpdate(obj);
    }
  });
  tg.on('close', function(code) {
    // иногда из-за багов telegram-cli падает, тогда пытаемся перезапустить его,
    // пропустив проблемные сообщения
    setTimeout(function(tg) {
      tg.kill(); // программа завершается при двойной отправке SIGINT
      tg.kill();
      tg.on('close', launchTelegram); // как только она завершится, снова
                                      // запускаем для получения обновлений
    }, RESTARTING_DELAY, spawn('./telegram-cli', { stdio: 'inherit' }));
  });
}

function processUpdate(upd) {
  if (upd.ID='UpdateNewMessage' &&
      upd.message_.content_.ID == 'MessageText' &&
      upd.message_.can_be_deleted_ &&
      upd.message_.content_.text_.search(obsceneLexicon)) {
    // если сообщение удолетворяет определённым критериям, отправляем
    // telegram-cli объект-команду на удаление
    tg.send({
      'ID': 'DeleteMessages',
      'chat_id_': upd.message_.chat_id_,
      'message_ids_': [ upd.message_.id_ ]
    });
  }
}

launchTelegram(); // запускаем всю эту машинерию
```

Надеюсь, теперь вам будет проще реализовать свою задачу. По сути, обновления можно игнорировать, например, переведя его в режим демона и подключаясь к нему по TCP.

Comment: Вообще автор на php хотел сделать.

Comment: @ilyaplot, но у меня нету примера на PHP (и да, метка чего-то не проставлена)

Comment: добавил метку :)