# Взаимодействие с Telegram

Tags: telegram

Работал с VK API. [Там](https://vk.com/dev/first_guide) конкретно описывалось, что нужно сформировать HTTP-запрос и получить в ответ JSON-ответ. Написано прозрачно.

А вот как работать с Telegram API, которое не для ботов, а именно для прямого взаимодействия с сервером? Каким образом посылать и получать запросы?

Comment: где ссыль или примеры то?

Comment: начать надо не с API а с протокола видимо.

Comment: В чём проблема? По-моему довольно внятно написано https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Comment: @hedgehogues, речь не об API для ботов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Telgram Core API работает, используя [MtProto](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto) — протокол собственной разработки. Он хоть и обеспечивает и шифрование, и большинство сервисов, что предоставляет TLS, всё же сильно от него отличается. (Напомню, что HTTPS есть обычный HTTP поверх TLS, а который уже в свою очередь строится поверх TCP).

MtProto же может работать, используя довольно разнообразный транспорт (TCP, HTTP и пр.) Протокол состоит из двух основных частей: для облачных чатов, которые доступны на любом авторизованном устройстве, и для секретных чатов, которые целиком зашифрованы от устройства до устройства (end-to-end).

Основной протокол телеграма позволяет обмениваться с сервером сообщениями произвольной конечной длины. Под сообщениями тут подразумеваются некие порции данных: установка параметров, запрос списка чатов, уведомления и пр. Словом, всё, что представляет собой т.н. высокоуровневый API. Полную схему найдёте на сайте Telegram https://core.telegram.org/schema.

К счастью, для взаимодействия по MtProto вам не обязательно его реализовывать самостоятельно. Можно воспользоваться готовым приложением [telegram-cli](https://valtman.name/telegram-cli). Его код закрыт (по крайней мере часть, связанная с протоколом). Если есть желание изучить протокол подробнее, на мой взгляд, актуальный код можно найти в репозитории [Telegram Desktop](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/v1.0.24/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/mtp_instance.h).

Пример скрипта для **telegram-cli** смотрите в [другом моём ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621655).

*NB:* пожалуйста, не путайте всё вышесказанное с Telegram Bot API. Это уже обычный Rest API и работает поверх привычного HTTPS (как у ВКонтакте, так же как и API множества других популярных сервисов).

Comment: То бишь, чтобы отправить/получить хоть какую-нибудь информацию, нужно сообщиться с серверами только по MTProto?

Comment: MtProto обязателен, только если вы пытаетесь написать клиент для Telegram. Если ваша цель — бот, для вас есть Rest API по HTTPS. Не понятно, какую информацию вы хотите получить от телеграм.

Comment: Нет, планировался как раз клиент. Спасибо за информацию

Comment: В таком случае вам может быть полезна библиотека [tdlib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib)

Comment: Java мне не подходит, к сожалению